# Get ControollerContext.RouteValues from POST action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I created partial view and I call it like this:

```
  @{Html.RenderAction("_SearchPartial", "Search", new { RenderVillaOption=true,RenderHotelOption=true,Frame=true,RenderAccommodationOption=true,RenderRentACarOption=true});}
```

I pass some values because I want them to be seen near the declaration od partial view and I controller I can get this values which is fine.
Than I post to some action inside SearchController. I would like to get this "Options" (route values I specified inside partial view declaration. How to achive that?
This is action method:

```
 public string SearchAndRedirect([FromBody] SearchAPIModel searchModel)
    {
        var redirectUrl = "";

        var c = ControllerContext;
        switch (searchModel.ProductType)
```

Comment: Please post your search controller method, which you used to call the partial view

Answer (score 0):

Get them as parameters inside your ActionMethod:

```
    public ActionResult Search(bool RenderVillaOption, bool RenderHotelOption, bool Framem ...  )
    {
    }
```

Comment: Is there any other way, I already receive some object which values depend on user interaction with search box. I don't want to mix these object which is user bahavoiur and search box options which is completely somethng else.

Comment: I think you can make a ViewModel with your Option properties and pass it to your partial, where you can set the values and Post them to your action as OptionsViewModel for example, but i need to see your action.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to @vortex answer, considering your comment you can use [Request.Params](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.params(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public ActionResult Search(...)
{
     var renderVillaOption = Request.Params["RenderVillaOption"];
}
```